# Jordan decomposition functional $C^*$-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, topological-vector-spaces, convex-hulls, locally-convex-spaces

Consider the following fragment from the thesis *Injective and Semidiscrete von Neumann Algebras* by Rasmus Sylvester Bryder:

[image]

Why is the boxed equality true? In particular, I don't see why the right hand side is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $S$ are either states, or negatives of states. So a convex combination $\psi$ of elements in $S$ looks like
$$
\psi=\sum_{j=1}^nt_j\phi_j+\sum_{j=n+1}^m t_j (-\phi_j),
$$
where $\phi_j$ is a state and $t_j\geq0$ for all $j$, and $\sum_jt_j=1$. Recall that a convex combination of states is a state. Let
$$
\lambda=\sum_{j=1}^nt_j,\quad \mu=\sum_{j=n+1}^m t_j,
$$
and
$$
\omega_1=\tfrac1\lambda\,\sum_{j=1}^nt_j\phi_j,\qquad 
\omega_2=\tfrac1\mu\,\sum_{j=n+1}^mt_j\phi_j.
$$
Then $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are states, $\lambda+\mu=1$, and
$$
\psi=\lambda\omega_1-\mu\omega_2,
$$

Comment: This answer contains some typos. I think you need to have $\omega_1 = \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n (t_j/\lambda) \phi_j$ for instance.

Comment: Such $\omega_1$ is not a state: you have $$\omega_1(1)=\lambda\sum_{j=1}^n(t_j/\lambda)=\sum_{j=1}^nt_j<1.$$

Comment: Yes clearly you are right. Apologies.

Comment: None needed. $ $